# 22.04 does not include exfat-utils

Tags: 22.04, exfat

I'm getting the error `unknown filesystem type 'exfat'` and have seen all the posts and articles that reference installing `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse`.  However, `exfat-utils` is not available under 22.04 LTS.  I found `exfat-progs` and tried that but it still gives the error when attempting to mount an exFat formatted partition.

An attempt to locate `exfat-utils` confirms it is not in jammy repos:

```
$ rmadison exfat-utils
 exfat-utils | 1.0.1-1 | trusty/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 exfat-utils | 1.2.3-1 | xenial/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 exfat-utils | 1.2.8-1 | bionic/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 exfat-utils | 1.3.0-1 | focal/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 exfat-utils | 1.3.0-2 | impish/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Comment: It's not needed because exfat support is built into the kernel. That makes this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). I suggest that you ask about and provide details about your actual problem.

Comment: Did you use the correct spelling - `exfatprogs` not `exfat-progs`?

Comment: exFAT read-write support is in the kernel. To [create, fsck, or label](http://sven.stormbind.net/blog/posts/deb_debian_and_exfat/) an exFAT partition, you need the `exfatprogs` package.

Comment: Wanted to acknowledge your comment; thanks.  I'm pretty sure that the name 'exfat-progs' was one I found while searching for likely related packages.  But it's been long enough I'll have to check and report back.

Comment: @Carolus exFat option is greyed out when I try to format a partition via Disks. I tried to install it via Terminal [sudo apt install exfatprogs] but it responds with "package exfatprogs not available, but is reffered to by another package. Package exfatprogs has no installation candidate".

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy One likely cause is that you do not have the Universe repository activated. I found that information when searching for the package [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=exfatprogs&searchon=names) where it states `[universe]` for 22.04.